# how create array like example in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I must send some parameters with api as json format and there is sample for one of parametes like below:

```
[
 [
   {"PassengerAge":20,"Gender":false}
 ]
]
```

Now i create json but how can i put it on two array( [[]] ) that be like up?

```
$rooms = json_encode(["PassengerAge"=>20,"Gender"=>false]);
```

Now `$rooms` export is:

```
{"PassengerAge":20,"Gender":false}
```

so how can i convert `$rooms` to example in laravel?

Comment: try using `$rooms->toArray()`

Comment: @AnkitJindal how can you call a method on a string?

Comment: As per your code it is shown as an object `{"PassengerAge":20,"Gender":false}`

Comment: @AnkitJindal `json_encode` returns a string, that is how the string looks when you output it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get output like the example above, you can wrap this `json` in as many arrays as you want:

```
$rooms = json_encode([[["PassengerAge"=>20,"Gender"=>false]]]);
```

This will give the following output:

```
"[[{"PassengerAge":20,"Gender":false}]]"
```

When you decode this:

```
json_decode($rooms)
```

You get the following structure:

```
  [
     [
       {#4768
         +"PassengerAge": 20,
         +"Gender": false,
       },
     ],
   ]
```

Tested this in `tinker`